# Problemas con el login en laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, login, autenticación

. La aplicación debe que contar con un inicio de sesión donde se ingrese el tipo de usuario, el
número de identificación y la contraseña, se debe que validar si es el primer ingreso para que
solicite la actualización de la contraseña.

Tengo un LoginRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Factory as ValidationFactory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            //
            'id_number' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'type' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    
    
}
```

tengo un login controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function show()
    {
        return view('auth.login');  
    }

    public function login(LoginRequest $request) {

        $credentials = $request->only('id_number', 'password', 'type');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            $user = Auth::user();

            if ($user->first_login) {
                return redirect()->route('changepassword');
            }

            
            if ($user->type == 'professional') {
                return redirect()->route('professional');
            } elseif ($user->type == 'patient') {
                return redirect()->route('patient');
            }
        }

        return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
            'error' => 'Credenciales incorrectas.',
        ]);
    }

    public function changePassword()
    {
        return view('auth.changepassword');
    }
   
    public function updatePassword(LoginRequest $request)
       {
        $user = Auth::user();
      
        if (Hash::check($request->input('old_password'), $user->password)) {
            $user->password = bcrypt($request->input('new_password'));
            $user->first_login = false;
            dd($user);

            $user = User::create($user);

            if ($user->type == 'professional') {
                return redirect()->route('professional');
            } elseif ($user->type == 'patient') {
                return redirect()->route('patient');
            }
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
                'error' => 'La antigua contraseña es incorrecta.',
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

estoy intentado validar si el usuario ya ingreso por primera vez y que le pida cambiar la contraseña por una nueva, luego lo envié a otra vista para que cambie la contraseña

luego de cambiar la contraseña volver al inicio de sesión

volver al ingresar con la nueva contraseña y al elegir el tipo sea professional o patient lo envié a su respectiva pagina después de logearse.